# Cannot replace string with sed. Getting unknown option

Tags: sed

I am trying to replace a string with `sed` (stream editor), however I am getting errors thrown back. Probably because I am not using the string correctly, because of the symbols.

I am trying to replace the following string:

```
<VirtualHost |IP|:|PORT_80| |MULTI_IP|>
```

with

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080 |IP|:8080 |MULTI_IP|>
```

In the file called `virtual_host2.conf`

Buw when I try several things, I always get errors back like:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 90: unterminated `s' command
sed: -e expression #1, char 20: unknown option to `s'
```

I am not that experienced with `sed`, but I can replace text strings normally. But I think because of the symbols in the current string, like `|`, `<` and `>` it doesn't work like I would.

Can someone please give me a working example on how to replace the above?
Or point me in the right direction.

I tried the following myself:

```
sed -i 's<VirtualHost |IP|:|PORT_80| |MULTI_IP|>/<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080 |IP|:8080 |MULTI_IP|>' /virtual_host2.conf

sed -i 's|<VirtualHost |IP|:|PORT_80| |MULTI_IP|>|<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080 |IP|:8080 |MULTI_IP|>|g' /virtual_host2.conf
```

But both give the error as mentioned above.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You omit `/` in `sed 's///'` pattern. **Try this**:

```
sed 's/<VirtualHost |IP|:|PORT_80| |MULTI_IP|>/<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080 |IP|:8080 |MULTI_IP|>/' /virtual_host2.conf
```

And if everything is ok, add `-i` option to execut real replacement in file.

`g` option in `'s///g'` pattern perform global replacement of all occurances, not the first in each line.

---

You can use some other symbols as delimeter, such as `'s|||'`, but it not make sense in your example because you need to quote each `|` symbol. This command will get the same output:

```
sed 's|<VirtualHost \|IP\|:\|PORT_80\| \|MULTI_IP\|>|<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080 \|IP\|:8080 \|MULTI_IP\|>|' /virtual_host2.conf
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and details. I didn't even know if I used sed without "i" that it would show the changes. Thank you kindly. Learned a new thing today.

Comment: @Restafval, great! See this tutorial for more tricks with sed: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html